# SharePoint 2013 - Central Admin access

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, central-administration

I can access the CA from the app server. However, when I go to my laptop and try the CA it prompts me for credentials 3 times then the screen is blank.

Any idea what's happening. IIS looks good (anon - disabled, windows auth - enabled)

Answer (score 0):

In case your laptop connected to the same network, try to browse the Central Administration URL via the IP server as  `http://serverIP:Port` and check the result.

If the issue still persists, try to Configure AAM for the Central Administration as the following:

**Steps:**

- Configure alternate access mapping for the Central Administration.
- Configure Hosts file.
- Disable loop Back Check
- Add “A” record on DNS server to point the server IP.

All the detail steps mentioned at [A REAL SCENARIO FOR CONFIGURING ALTERNATE ACCESS MAPPING INSIDE SHAREPOINT SERVER 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/26/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Answer (score -1):

I enabled "Basic Authentication" in IIS and now I can access CA from other than SharePoint servers or SP app servers.

Comment: You should never mess around directly in IIS if you want to change authentication-settings. Those settings can be found in CentralAdmin in your WebApplication settings ("Authentication Providers"). If this helped you out, someone previous might have changed settings directly in IIS.